# Return updated unsorted dict in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I am trying to merge some dicts with saving their items on their own places like it is working in python using `dict.update()`, but i have some troubles with it in Ansible.

For example, I have two dicts:

```
dict1:
  c_value: None

dict2:
  b_value: None
  a_value: None
```

I want to merge them with saving order:

```
dict3:
  c_value: None
  b_value: None
  a_value: None
```

I have tried 2 solutions, using jinja2 and ansible filter combine. All of them works fine in jinja2 online editors, but if i use it in ansible - debugging shows that I have sorted dict by key name:

```
dict3:
  a_value: None
  b_value: None
  c_value: None
```

Jinja2 template: `{%-set _ = dict1.update(dict2) -%}{{- dict1 -}}`

Ansible combine: `dict1 | combine(dict2)`

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary aka [mapping](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#3211-nodes) is:

> *"an **unordered** set of key/value node pairs, ..."*

In other words, in YAML, there is no order in the dictionary's keys. What you see is probably [Python 3.7+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html):

> *"A dictionary now displays in the lexical order that variables were defined. Previously, the order was undefined."*

See what Python your version of Ansible uses (on the controller)

```bash
shell> ansible --version
ansible [core 2.14.3]
  ...
  python version = 3.9.17 (main, Jun  6 2023, 20:11:04) [GCC 9.4.0] (/usr/bin/python3.9)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

Given the dictionaries

```yaml
  dict1:
    c_value: None
  dict2:
    b_value: None
    a_value: None
```

combine them

```yaml
  dict3: "{{ dict1|combine(dict2) }}"
```

- The keys are ordered lexicographically by Python 3.7+

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ dict3 }}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
    a_value: None
    b_value: None
    c_value: None
```

- You have to declare another order of keys if you want to. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for k in key_order %}
          {{ k }}: {{ dict3[k] }}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        key_order: [c_value, b_value, a_value]
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    c_value: None
    b_value: None
    a_value: None
```

- But, if you convert the text to YAML you get the ordered keys again

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% for k in key_order %}
          {{ k }}: {{ dict3[k] }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}
      vars:
        key_order: [c_value, b_value, a_value]
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
    a_value: None
    b_value: None
    c_value: None
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    dict1:
      c_value: None
    dict2:
      b_value: None
      a_value: None

    dict3: "{{ dict1|combine(dict2) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ dict3 }}

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for k in key_order %}
          {{ k }}: {{ dict3[k] }}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        key_order: [c_value, b_value, a_value]

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% for k in key_order %}
          {{ k }}: {{ dict3[k] }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}
      vars:
        key_order: [c_value, b_value, a_value]
```